# Why won't CSS3 border radius work on images on webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari)?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

This works in firefox 4 and ie9 but not chrome or safari. It also doesn't work in opera but who cares about that. So how to get it to work?

```
img { width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 3px solid #fff; 

-moz-border-radius: 10px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
border-radius: 10px; 

}
```

Comment: "It also doesn't work in Opera but who cares about that"? Wow, I hope I never work with someone like you. Yuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A workaround is to use a `div` and set the background of the `div` to the image.

```
.rounded { 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
    border: 3px solid #fff; 

    -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
    border-radius: 10px; 

    background: url(image.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: right, I just wished it was possible to do directly on the image itself. Oh well.

Comment: @Jacob You can automate the switch with JavaScript from `img` to this if you like.

Answer (score 1):

you are using white as your border.  what color is your background?  I'm not seeing any issues on my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m5NP3/

Comment: thought maybe the image was popping out over the corners, but it looks fine with a black bg too http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/m5NP3/1/